# Why can't I file my taxes electronically if I include Form 1116 Schedule B?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, software

I am using one of the popular tax programs to do my income taxes. The program says that if I need form 1116 schedule B then I cannot file my taxes electronically. I am wondering if the problem is with the software or is the problem due to a problem at the IRS?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the software. My CPA has been able to file for me electronically with Form 1116 Schedule B on the return.